What is the Best Transition State Search Method
I want to find transition states (TS) on the potential energy surface (PES) of small/medium reactions with sinle-ended methods. For example the reaction network from here. I've been looking at different methods for transition state search, like the Eigenvector Method, several other quasi-Newton methods and also Anharmonic Downward Distortion. Nevertheless, I've not been able to find out what the current standard for TS search is, or even what method is best for which use-case. Is there a "best" way of searching for TS on high dimensional PES?

There is no best way. Look at nudged elastic band methods, these are very good.
